# Spring - Convert JSON String to JSON object

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

I have the `user` table stored as following:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|      id             |     name         |    address                       
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|      1              |     ken          | {"street":"Street 1","city":"City1", "country":"USA"}       |     
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

My POJO:

```
public class User{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String address;
    //setters and getters
}
```

In my RESTful services i wish to have the following JSON as response when i call for my API:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "ken",
   "address":{
        "street":"Street 1",
        "city":"City1", 
        "country":"USA"
   }
}
```

I can do this by changing my `address` in POJO to a address object, then map the string into the adress object.

But is there any other ways that i keep my address as string in POJO, then it will render as JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `@JsonSerialize` on your property:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomeSerializer.class)
private String address;


public class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<String>{
    public CustomSerializer(){
        this(null);
    }
    public CustomSerializer(Class<String> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(String address, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(new ObjectMapper().readTree(address));
    }
}
```